# Add tiles to both sides of TileMap List in MonoGame

Tags: c#, monogame

This is what my tile map looks like (red highlighting added for clarity):

[image]

My code:

```
private List<List<int>> _layoutLayer = new List<List<int>>(50); // Layout Layer
private List<List<int>> _trLayer = new List<List<int>>(50); // Transitional Layer
private List<List<int>> _entityLayer = new List<List<int>>(50); // Object Layer
private List<List<int>> _logicLayer = new List<List<int>>(50); // Logic Layer

// To add a tile
if (inputManager.IsMouseHeld(true))
{
    try
    {
        switch (_currentLayer)
        {
            case LayerRepresentation.LayoutLayer:
                _layoutLayer[_gridMouseY][_gridMouseX] = _currentTile;
                break;
            case LayerRepresentation.TransitionalLayer:
                _trLayer[_gridMouseY][_gridMouseX] = _currentTile;
                break;
            case LayerRepresentation.EntityLayer:
                _entityLayer[_gridMouseY][_gridMouseX] = _currentTile;
                break;
            case LayerRepresentation.LogicLayer:
                _logicLayer[_gridMouseY][_gridMouseX] = _currentTile;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
         // Player clicked outside of map bounds, add specified amount of tiles to map
    }
}
```

What I need:

When the player clicks outside of map bounds for example on the point A, add the amount of tiles between point A and the map to the map's height. Do the same with point B, but add to the map width instead.

What I've tried:

```
    // Inside the above catch block
    if (_mapHeight - _gridMouseY == 0 && _gridMouseX < _mapWidth && _gridMouseX > -1)
    {
        List<int> tempDefaultLayout = new List<int>();
        List<int> tempDefaultOther = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _layoutLayer[0].Count; i++)
        {
            tempDefaultLayout.Add(0);
            tempDefaultOther.Add(-1);
        }
        _layoutLayer.Insert(_gridMouseY, tempDefaultLayout);
        _trLayer.Insert(_gridMouseY, tempDefaultOther);
        _entityLayer.Insert(_gridMouseY, tempDefaultOther);
        _logicLayer.Insert(_gridMouseY, tempDefaultOther);
        _mapHeight++;
    }
    else if (_mapWidth - _gridMouseX == 0 && _gridMouseY < _mapHeight && _gridMouseY > -1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _layoutLayer.Count; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _layoutLayer[y].Count; x++)
            {
                if (_layoutLayer[y].Count <= _mapWidth)
                {
                    _layoutLayer[y].Add(0);
                    _trLayer[y].Add(-1);
                    _entityLayer[y].Add(-1);
                    _logicLayer[y].Add(-1);
                }
            }
        }
        _mapWidth++;
    }
    return;
```

The problems:

> The first part is about adding tiles to the height (only one row at a time) Adding the temp `List`s to the layer `List`s with `List.Add()` doesn't work, I don't know why. I used `List.Insert` instead.
>
> The second part is used to add a single column to the map one at a time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out:

Using `Add()` actually works and the problem was in the loop where I was adding the `List<int>`s to my `List<List<int>>`s. I was adding the wrong amount (about 430, instead of the 16 I wanted). I couldn't spot this bug earlier because the four hundred-something lists were all empty and didn't render. So `Add()` was adding the `tempList` to position 431 or something, and trying to index the layer by `[x]` at `[y] = 16` so it threw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. When I fixed the loop there `Add()` was working as expected.

I also removed the try/catch as it was bad for the exception trace and instead made actual logic that detects clicks outside of the map and `Add()`s elements to my lists before indexing to place/delete a tile.